Design a CFG that accepts $\{ a^n b^m \mid 0 \leq n \leq 3m + 1 \}$
I've been stuck on this for 2 days now and my exam in in 2 days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Closest i could Achieve was: ->S, S->(lambda), S->abB, S->aabB, S->aaabB, B->S, B-> (lambda), B->a.

What CFG did you find with its language the closest you could achieve?

Closest i could Achieve was: ->S, S->(lambda), S->abB, S->aabB, S->aaabB, B->S, B-> (lambda), B->a.

(lambda epsilon? In a post body, you can use $L^AT_EX: \lambda \epsilon$.)

(FWIW, I find your grammar quite close. You need an idea to keep every $b$ to the right of the last $a$.)

I see two problems:
$L_3 = \{~a^n b^m~\mid~0 \leq n \leq 3m~\}$
$L_{+1} = L_3\cup aL_3$

For the language $L = \{ a^n b^m \mid 0 \leq n \leq 3m + 1, m \geq 1 \}$,
When $m=1$, then $n \in [0, 4]$, and the corresponding strings are $\{ a^0b,a^1b, a^2b, a^3b, a^4b \}$.
That is for each $b$, the corresponding $a$'s can be between $0$ to $4$. Whenever my grammar generates a $b$ it should generate at max $4$ $a$'s.
So, the corresponding grammar should be -
$$S \to b \mid aSb\mid aaSb\mid aaaSb\mid aaaaSb$$

But if your language is $L_1 = \{ a^n b^m \mid 0 \leq n \leq 3m + 1, m \geq 0 \}$,
Then for $m=0$ , $n \in [0, 1]$ which would mean $\{ a, \varepsilon\} \in L_{1}$, adding more terminals to the grammar wouldn't work.
$$S \to \varepsilon \mid a\mid b \mid aSb\mid aaSb\mid aaaSb\mid aaaaSb$$
The above grammar can generate $w = aaaaab$ ($S \implies aaaaSb \implies aaaaab $), and $w \notin L_1$. This however, can easily be fixed by getting rid of the production, $S \to aaaaSb$. So, the correct grammar should be,
$$S \to \varepsilon\mid a\mid b \mid aSb\mid aaSb\mid aaaSb$$

Try to start the argument with up to $3 a$s for each $b$.
